# Concatenating several different chars into 1 string

Tags: c++

I have several char variables which contain various chars which are filled in by some logic that I have created. Basically I am looking for a way to add these to a string that I have already created, but I am unsure of how to do this in one simple method and not appending all the chars individually to the string, which is particularly slow.

```
string test;
char test1, test2, test3, test4, test5;
...Some logic here to populate the chars

test += test1 + test2, etc
```

The method above doesn't work as it adds the values together literally, as in the integer values of the char to create one number at the end. This is my current (and very inefficient) method of doing it:

```
test += test1;
test += test2;
test += test3;
test += test4;
test += test5;
```

Is there a way I can concatenate these chars into 1 string more simply?

NOTE: It is worth mentioning that I know this method suffices but I am also looking to improve the performance here as well

Comment: What's wrong with your approach? It looks pretty simple to me.

Comment: Its a pretty slow and inefficient way of doing, I wanted to try improve the performance

Comment: `push_back()` ?? `test += test1` This could be an efficient method than `test1 + test2`

Comment: @Jono_2007 Trust me, you don't need to worry about those kinds of optimizations. Here's a rule of thumb - if it's not in a cycle that executes **at least** 1,000,000 times, don't worry whether it takes 5 or 10 clock cycles.

Comment: @Jono_2007 Also, don't ask performance questions like that. These have been asked ad nauseum here and everyone's sick of them.

Comment: The thing with the += operator in the std::string class is that each time you use it, the string is being resized, i.e., a new longer string is created, then the original string plus the character are copied to the new string and then the original string is release. So, @Danvil answer seems pretty logical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) to make enough room in the string and place your characters by using `operator[]`:

```
std::string result = "hello"
char c1 = '1', c2 = 'F', c3 = '%';

size_t len = result.size();
result.resize(len + 3);
result[len] = c1;
result[len+1] = c2;
result[len+2] = c3;
```

Result: `hello1F%`

If your chars are in an array it is even simpler by using [insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert):

```
   std::string result = "hello";
   char c[10]; // 10 characters
   result.insert(result.end(), &c[0], 10); // add 10 characters to end of string
```

Answer (score 1):

Less code. More efficient?

```
string test;
char test1[6];

// fill in test1[0], test1[1], etc, setting test[5]=0

test += test1;
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe use `stringstream` : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/

```
stringstream ss;
ss << test1 << test2 << test3 << test4 << test5
test = ss.str();
```

Or why not create a variable of type `char[5]` and work on its characters individually (as if they were test1, 2,  ...) and at the end you have your string without having to do anything ...

Comment: This method does work but but I found Danvils answer processed the concatenation faster